# nginx server fails to show images from backend

Tags: php, postgresql, nginx, centos, broken-image

A website stopped showing images (shows broken image link).

Two facts there:

- path to these images is correct
- request url: https://www.example.tld/?image=yAZiOJXRVwCGEVG8.png&size=big (as it should be)

But, if I copy this link to a web browser, in case of Mozilla I see "The image "link to the image" cannot be displayed because it contains errors".

Fact number three:

- If I launch a copy of this website on localhost under apache2 (back and front) images are shown correctly. So this is why I tend to think the problem is somewhere in nginx.

Fact number four:

- Other info like text which also comes from backend is there and fine.

Any suggestions?

UPD. Code for showing news (each news has image)

```
<?php
$datalayer = new \DataLayer\DataLayer();
$page = array_key_exists('page', $parameters) ? $parameters['page'] : 1;
$count = array_key_exists('count', $parameters) ? $parameters['count'] : 8;
$request = new \DataLayer\Main\Requests\GetNews($page, $count);
$type = array_key_exists('type', $parameters) ? $parameters['type'] : 'horizontal';

$news = $datalayer->processRequest('getNews', $request)['data'];
?>


<div class="news8 <?=($news->Page == $news->TotalPages ? " last" : "")?>">
  <?php foreach($news->News as $key => $row): ?>
  <a class="container" href="/?news=<?=$row->Id?>">
      <img class="header-image" src="<?=($row->Image ? './?image='.$row->Image.'&size=preview' : './media/imgs/ico-no-img.png')?>" />
      <div class="news-info">
          <div class="news-header"><?=$row->Title?></div>
          <div class="news-date"><?=date ("d.m.Y", time($row->Created))?></div>
      </div>
  </a>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Config

```
ssl.conf
#
# HTTPS server configuration
#

server {
     listen       443 ssl http2 default_server;

     server_name  www.hostname.example;
     root         /path/to/root;
     index       index.php index.html;

     ssl_certificate hostname_example.crt;
     ssl_certificate_key  hostname_example.key;

     ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:1m;
     ssl_session_timeout  10m;
     ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
     ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

     # Load configuration files for the default server block.
     include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

     location / {
     }

     error_page 404 /404.html;
         location = /40x.html {
     }

     error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
          location = /50x.html {
     }

     location ~ \.php$ {
         fastcgi_cache  portalName;
         fastcgi_cache_valid 200 301 302 304 60m;
         fastcgi_cache_key "$request_method$http_if_modified_since$http_if_none_match$host$request_uri";
         fastcgi_pass_header "X-Accel-Expires";    
         fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
         fastcgi_index index.php;
         fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
         fastcgi_param HTTP_IF_NONE_MATCH $http_if_none_match;
         fastcgi_param HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE $http_if_modified_since;
         fastcgi_param HTTP_X_REAL_IP $remote_addr;
         include        fastcgi_params;
     }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you should show us the code you use to get the image

Comment: And show us your nginx config for that

Comment: What is the access log entry for retrieving the image? It seems that `/index.php` delivers the image. Is it setting the correct `content-type`?

Comment: @RichardSmith I'm not sure that I understood your fully, but here is an example of what I see in access.log of nginx
```hostname - - [11/Sep/2018:time] "GET /?image=YMby8e_M_RhbAWnX.jpeg&size=preview HTTP/2.0" 200 23005 "https://hostname.tld/" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 11_4_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/11.0 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1" "-"```

Comment: You can check the content type using your browser's tools or the command line utility `curl`. For example: `curl -I https://www.example.tld/?image=YMby8e_M_RhbAWnX.jpeg&size=preview`

Comment: @RichardSmith seems Ok. ```content-type: image/jpeg```. But image itself didn't load in browser.

Comment: I guess the only other test is to use `curl` to save it to a file and see if it looks like a jpeg image. For example: `curl https://www.example.tld/?image=YMby8e_M_RhbAWnX.jpeg&size=preview > filename.jpg`

Comment: It supposed to be 23K according to the access log. Are you sure you didn't leave the `-I` option in?

Comment: @RichardSmith "The file could not be opened. It may be damaged or use a file format that Preview doesn't recognize"

Comment: So it isn't a jpeg file. And probably does not compare to the original file. You might want to open the file with an editor and see it there are any clues as to what's gone wrong.

Comment: @RichardSmith But this is what I've done. I tried to open this file with Preview software. So, what do you mean by "editor" ?

Comment: You need to see what's in the file. Use `less filename.jpg` (it will complain that it's binary, and if it isn't then that's your problem there). On the Mac, use `xxd filename.jpg | less` to see a hex dump of the file.

Comment: These images present in db, I can manually download them via ssh from backend server -- normal healthy images. Only frontend server can't figure out how to show them to users.

Comment: @RichardSmith it shows ```00000000: 0a0a``` only

Comment: You need to go back to the access log. That file is two bytes and cannot be the same file that was delivered in the access log and listed as 23005 bytes.

Comment: @RichardSmith The name is correct, I checked by downloading this exact file manually via ssh and its 23K. So my question is what do you reckon happened with this image while it was downloaded from host rather than directly?

Comment: I also tried to play with several other images, they show the same 2 bytes as the first one. ```00000000: 0a0a``` may be this can lead us to a clue. And at first I didn't see it, but there are also two dots after some spaces. Though can't image it changes much.

Comment: I do not understand why the access log states 23005 bytes, but the file only contains two. You need to look at the error log and wherever your PHP scripts write their errors.

Comment: @RichardSmith All right. Thank you for helping me investigate this problem further than I could have done it myself.